# Bootstrap flip div on click <a href> does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website and I am having a problem.

I am using this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/3caq0L8u/

to flip a div on a button click.

The button that will flip the div is in the "front" and "back" of the card. My problem is that it works fine on desktop but no buttons or

```
<a href>
```

are clickable. When I try to click them nothing happens.

I have a feeling it has something to do with this css but I cannot figure out what

```
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.inner{margin:0px !important;}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing that?

Thanks!

Comment: The demo does not include buttons or anchor tags, if you included them it might be easier to help.

Comment: Do you want to make them button or <a>??

Comment: @ovokuro I just updated the link to a fiddle with exactly what I am doing. Thank you!

Comment: @BlackBird Right now I am using <a> but either will work fine, the problem seems to be that the button is hidden by something else, I tried changing some z-indexes but that was not working. Thanks!

Comment: Which button is hidden??

Comment: What exactly is not working? I can flip the card back and forth, and I can click on the links on the card. What browser are you using?

Comment: The problem is, I am not able to click the links on a mobile device. Though all I have been able to test is mobile safari @ovokuro

Comment: Clicking "Show Player Stats", its going to Another part..........Then vise versa.

Comment: @BlackBird The twitter, twitch, youtube, and show player stats/info buttons. They are not hidden they are just not click-able on mobile safari and maybe more mobile browsers, I have not been able to test more than that

Comment: In mobile they are also working as desktop

Comment: @BlackBird it seems they are, would the fact that I am using handlebars to make this div with the response of an api make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your footer is resizing awkwardly and covering most of the screen on mobile. Add to your css:

```
footer {
   clear:both
}
```

This ensures it comes after the main content.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! But my main problem is on mobile you cant even touch the links, when you tap one nothing happens not even a highlighted state.

Comment: Can you flip the card on mobile Safari?

Comment: No I cannot flip the card on mobile safari or click the links on mobile safari, and I am not sure if you saw my comment on the main post, but one thing I forgot to mention is that I am making these divs with handlebarsjs after I get a response from my api, could that have anything to do with the z-position not working on mobile?

Comment: Are you checking the demo and your site? The demo works for me on Android mobile (can't check iOS)

Comment: If you would like to look at my site on android mobile to verify that it has the same problems as iOS you can look at it here:
https://beta.breakoutleague.org/team.html?id=32

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much, the one element on the page I didnt look at lol

Comment: You're welcome. Similar thing happened to me before!